# How to do a plotly graph after a dcast table?

Tags: r, plotly, dcast

I have a database including day and places, with other relevant information. I am currently using the `dcast` function in order to count each occurence in a day and place (that in the real database are represented by numbers). Later, I want to do a `plotly` grafic where day represents my x coordinate, place represents my y coordinate, and z will represent the number of ocurence.

I provide some dummy data here, to simplify:

```
day<-c(1,2,3)
place<-c("here", "there", "far away")
frequency<-c(1,2,4)

d<-data.frame(day,place,frequency)

z<-dcast(d, day~place, fill=0)
```

How can I plot this using plotly ?

Comment: You will have to be more specific. What would you like to have for x-axis (Day?) and y-axis (Frequency?)?

Comment: I wrote that: 'where day represents my x coordinate, place represents my y coordinate, and z will represent the number of ocurence. '
Basically (x,y,z)<-(day, place, frequency)

Comment: does not sound like the definition of volcano plot (for example [here](https://moderndata.plot.ly/interactive-volcano-plots-r-plotly/)). It sounds more like a 3D plot.

Comment: I believe I can use both, but either way, I do not understand to plot it with the data that I have. I was refering to something like the Basic 3D Surface Plot in this link: https://plot.ly/r/3d-surface-plots/

Comment: like: `plot_ly(data = d, x = ~day, y = ~place, z = ~frequency, mode = "markers")`?

Comment: the shape will be that, but i want to plot z that also should give my ( for the example above) than when it is day 1, and I am in 'there' it should mark 0. Basically the output of the function dcast.

Comment: Maybe someone will have a better answer but in the meantime, you could do: `d_long <- melt(z, id.vars=c("day"))` followed with `plot_ly(data = d_long, x = ~day, y = ~variable, z = ~value, mode = "markers")`.

Comment: The last answer provided helped me a lot! It is what I wanted to do

Comment: I added my comment  to my answer. So if it fixes your problem you could accept my answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really broad, but you could try this:

```
 place<-c("here", "there", "faraway")
 frequency<-c(1,2,4)

 d<-data.frame(day,place,frequency)

 z<-dcast(d, day~place, fill=0)
 z$day <- as.factor(z$day)
plot_ly(data = z, x = ~day, y = ~here, type = "bar", name = 'here') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~there, name = 'there') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~faraway, name = 'faraway') %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), barmode = 'group')
```

[image]

Edit: Following OP comments. You can put it back to long format and then plot.

```
d_long <- melt(z, id.vars=c("day"))
plot_ly(data = d_long, x = ~day, y = ~variable, z = ~value, mode = "markers")
```